# Example 11.27 in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In *Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds"* there is the following quoted piece of text:

> **Example 11.27:** Let $F : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the map given by $$(u, v) = F(x, y, z) = (x^2y, y\sin z)$$ and let $\omega \in \mathfrak{X}^*(\mathbb{R}^2) $  be the covector field $$\omega = u dv + v du$$...

Now my interpretation of this is that the author is defining the function $u = \pi_1 \circ F : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ where $\pi_1 : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is the standard projection function onto the first coordinate. And similar the author is defining $v = \pi_2 \circ F : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$. So essentially the author is saying that $u$ and $v$ are the first and second component functions of $F$ respectively in my interpretation.

But if my interpretation is correct then $du$ and $dv$ are covector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and not on $\mathbb{R}^2$. What is my mistake here and what is the correct interpretation of this piece of text?

Comment: I think your interpretation is correct, and this is thus a typo.

Comment: No, he's using $(u,v)$ for coordinates on $\Bbb R^2$, and you're thinking of $F^*u$ and $F^*v$ instead.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks! @TedShifrin

Answer (score 2):

A map $F:\Bbb{R}^3\to \Bbb{R}^2$ is specified by the data of *two* real valued functions depending (in this case smoothly) on the *three* coordinates on the domain. Write the coordinates on $\Bbb{R}^3$ as $(x,y,z)$ and write those of $\Bbb{R}^2$ as $(u,v)$. The first component function is $F^1=\pi_1\circ F$ and the second component is $F^2=\pi_2\circ F$ as in your notation. Sometimes the dependence of the pair $(u,v)$ on the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ introduced by the mapping is recorded as above:
$$ (u,v)=(x^2y,y\sin z)=(F^1(x,y,z),F^2(x,y,z)),$$
i.e. $u(x,y,z)=x^2y$ and $v(x,y,z)=y\sin z$. This is often how such transformations are written in calculus. I find this notation to be a bit ambiguous or confusing, but I think it is standard.

In any case, $u$ and $v$ are coordinate functions on $\Bbb{R}^2$ (the codomain) and $vdu+udv$ is indeed a differential $1-$form on $\Bbb{R}^2$.